# How can I get USSD code result to string?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, ussd

How can I get USSD code result to string?

My USSD run code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
  Intent : JIntent ;
  strNo : String;
begin
  strNo := 'tel:*101%23';
  Intent := TJIntent.Create ;
  Intent.setAction ( TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_CALL ) ;
  Intent.setData ( StrToJURI (  strNo ) ) ;
  SharedActivity.startActivity ( Intent ) ;
end;
```

It works, but I need to get USSD code result to string.

For Delphi 10.2 Tokyo - Firemonkey Android Platform.

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer here that is probably relevant to your problem:

[How to Get Response from USSD code from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066677/how-to-get-response-from-ussd-code-from-android)

However the solution on Github (see the link in the answer) looks quite involved, and some parts may need to be done in Java.